# How to compare getMonth() and a full date format?

Tags: typescript

How to compare this format `2019-02-22` to `getMonth()`?
`getMonth()` only results as single number like this month is `1`
I'm trying to get them compared
`date` is dynamic from the database with this format `2019-02-22 12:13:12` for example

```
where('date', '=', new Date().getMonth());
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what your `where` function comes from but that should help:

```js
const date = new Date('2019-02-22 12:13:12');
const currentDate = new Date();
const isSameMonth = date.getMonth() === currentDate.getMonth();

console.log(isSameMonth); // true as of 22 Feb 2019
```

Comment: it doesn't work using `where(new Date('date').getMonth(), '=', new Date().getMonth())`

Answer (score 0):

I often use Monent when I work with date-time. Moment [isSame](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) is fix with you desire

Comment: How do I use that on `where` part? I'm trying to get the value from the database